# Looped macro to create a new sheet, rename it, add data from the web, then loop back through until complete

Tags: vba, excel

Trying to create a macro to take a spreadsheet with two columns (one with names, the other with a URL to a sheet I need data from), create a new sheet for each row, rename that sheet according to the name in column A, then create a web query in the new sheet according to the URL in column B.

Here's the macro I tried compiling, but it's not working.

```
Sub CreateSheetsFromAList()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim src As Worksheet
    Dim tgt As Worksheet
    Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range, URLCell As Range

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set src = wb.Sheets("AllPlayers")
    Set MyRange = Sheets("AllPlayers").Range("A1")
    Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown))
    Set URLCell = Sheets("AllPlayers").Range("B1")
    Set URLCell = Range(URLCell, URLCell.End(xlDown))

    For Each MyCell In MyRange
        Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = MyCell.Value
        With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=URLCell, Destination:=Range("$A$2"))
        .Name = "2015"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebTables = """pgl_basic"""
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    Next MyCell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made some syntax tweaks that should help as well as error handling if the sheet name already exists.  Didn't make any changes to the `QueryTable.Add` method though.

```
Sub CreateSheetsFromAList()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim src As Worksheet
    Dim tgt As Worksheet
    Dim ActSht As Worksheet
    Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range, URLValue As Variant

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set src = wb.Sheets("AllPlayers")
    Set MyRange = src.Range("A1:A" & src.Range("A" & src.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

    For Each MyCell In MyRange
        On Error Resume Next
        Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = MyCell.Value
        If Err.Number > 0 Then
            Err.Clear
            MsgBox MyCell.Value & " sheet name already exists"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        On Error Goto 0
        URLValue = MyCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
        Set ActSht = Sheets(Chr(34) & MyCell.Value & Chr(34))
        With ActSht.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= "URL;" & URLValue, Destination:=ActSht.Range("A2"))
          .Name = "2015"
          .FieldNames = True
          .RowNumbers = False
          .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
          .PreserveFormatting = True
          .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
          .BackgroundQuery = True
          .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
          .SavePassword = False
          .SaveData = True
          .AdjustColumnWidth = True
          .RefreshPeriod = 0
          .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
          .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
          .WebTables = """pgl_basic"""
          .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
          .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
          .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
          .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
          .WebDisableRedirections = False
          .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With
    Next MyCell
End Sub
```

Comment: Wait, you forgot an `End With`.  Corrected in my code.

Comment: That seemed to fix the "Next w/out For" issue, but I'm now getting another error:

"Run-time error '1004':
Application-defined or object-defined error"

It highlights the line 

     With Sheets(MyCell.Value).QueryTables.Add(Connection:=URLValue, Destination:=Sheets(MyCell.Value).Range("$A$2"))

Comment: I hit Enter and it submitted my comment when I was trying to move to a new line to enter the error... check previosu comment for edit.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still getting an error; I tried seeing what it might be caused by myself but I'm still lost here.  "Run-time error 9" at this line  Set ActSht = Sheets(Chr(34) & MyCell.Value & Chr(34))

Comment: I hate to do this because it is sloppy by try changing that line that has the error to `Set ActSht = Sheets(Sheets.Count)`

Comment: (Tried to move to chat, it said I didn't have enough Rep to chat... sorry for the extended comments window.)

I tried that, it went back to Run-time error 1004 on the following line: 
        With ActSht.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=URLValue, Destination:=ActSht.Range("A2"))

Comment: Tried moving to chat as well... but can't bring you in.  Just updated.  Try new edit.

Comment: Fixed it by changing that line to:  With ActSht.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= "URL;" & URLValue, Destination:=ActSht.Range("A2"))